# Kubuntu 17.04 AMD graphics driver issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, kubuntu, radeon, amd-graphics

I am running Kubuntu 17.04 with a Radeon R7 M265 graphics card. However, the graphics card is not being used. This is clear in running games as well as peeking at general system info. Running the command `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`

gets the only result:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500
        Kernel driver in use: i915

However, I have confirmed the fact that the graphics card is  at least recognized. Furthermore, the radeon open source drivers are installed as far as I can tell. The Driver Manager does not recognize that these drivers exist.

I have read several articles with possible fixes that amounted to no help. Is there something that I'm missing? I'm a new Ubuntu user; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use "3D" instead of "VGA" and you'll see the other card. AFAIK there's currently no *graphical* way to switch cards so you may try to enabled the discrete only at UEFI settings, if such option is available. Otherwise https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics